# Codeception Conditional Assertions with custom functions

Tags: php, codeception

So we got Codeception to look at a different database while testing another database in the same Cept file

What I need help with is getting the functions `CanSeeInMasterDatabase` and `CantSeeInMasterDatabase` to throw errors once the test completes.
In other words the known Codeception functions that begin with "canSee" and "cantSee" etc allow the tests to keep running in the event one of them fails and once the test is complete it will give you a little summary of what failed at the end.

In the below functions I am getting the correct error during the test (see below) but not getting a summary of errors at end of the test

> ←[36m SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE columnname= "1" AND field1= "data"
>   ←[39m
>   ←[36m Error: Database value could be found in tablename
>   ←[39m

The end of my test looks like, expecting to see something like "there was 1 error etc etc etc"

> ←[37;45m PASSED
>    ←[39;49m
>   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
>
> Time: 28.09 seconds, Memory: 31.50Mb
>   ←[30;42mOK (1 test, 0
>   assertions)
>   ←[0m

We have a custom file with 4 functions like so

```
public function seeInMasterDatabase($tableName, $conditionArray) {
    $databaseReturn = $this->grabFromMasterDatabase($tableName, $conditionArray);

    if (empty($databaseReturn)) {
         $this->fail('Error: Database value could not be found in '  . $tableName);
    }

}

public function dontSeeInMasterDatabase($tableName, $conditionArray) {
    $databaseReturn = $this->grabFromMasterDatabase($tableName, $conditionArray);

    if (!empty($databaseReturn)) {
        $this->fail('Error: Database value could be found in '  . $tableName);
    }

}

public function canSeeInMaster($tableName, $conditionArray) {
    $databaseReturn = $this->grabFromMasterDatabase($tableName, $conditionArray);

    if (empty($databaseReturn)) {
        $this->debug('Error: Database value could be found in ' . $tableName);  
    }
}

public function cantSeeInMaster($tableName, $conditionArray) {
    $databaseReturn = $this->grabFromMasterDatabase($tableName, $conditionArray);

    if (!empty($databaseReturn)) {
        $this->debug('Error: Database value could be found in ' . $tableName);  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you use `fail` in one pair of methods and `debug` in another?

You haven't pasted the code of your test, but it looks like `Error: Database value could be found in tablename` is the output of `debug` method.
The `fail` should produce expected result.

But I recommend rewriting your helper methods to use `assertEmpty`, `assertNotEmpty`:

```
public function seeInMasterDatabase($tableName, $conditionArray) {
    $databaseReturn = $this->grabFromMasterDatabase($tableName, $conditionArray);
    $this->assertNotEmpty($databaseReturn, 'Database value could not be found in '  . $tableName);
}

public function dontSeeInMasterDatabase($tableName, $conditionArray) {
    $databaseReturn = $this->grabFromMasterDatabase($tableName, $conditionArray);
    $this->assertEmpty($databaseReturn, 'Database value could be found in '  . $tableName);
}
```

In this way assertions will be counted and reported correctly.

Edit: Do not declare `can` methods, `can` and `cant` methods are automatically generated for all `see` and `dontSee` methods.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I have replaced the debug with assertnotempty. the issue i am running into now is for example when i run a Cept with:     
$I->canSeeInMaster("tablename", array("column" => 2, "columntwo" =>'test'));
    $I->canSeeInMaster("tablename", array("column" => 1, "column2" =>'test'));
the top one is correct, the bottom one isnt therefore I should get the assertion that this line failed but the test should keep going

Comment: im trying to accomplish this 
#### Conditional Assertions
  266  
  267: Sometimes you don't want the test to be stopped when an assertion fails. Maybe you have a long-running test and you want it to run to the end. In this case you can use conditional assertions. Each `see` method has a corresponding `canSee` method, and `dontSee` has a `cantSee` method.

Comment: Do not declare `can` methods, `can` and `cant` methods are automatically generated for all `see` and `dontSee` methods.

Comment: I get what your saying but these methods are only generated when using codeception, i am not in vendor code, I am using a customer file with these helper functions